# Python version through console is different from downloaded?

Tags: python

Recently, I have downloaded Python 3.10, after installation I opened the console to check the version but what I got is version 2.7.16 !!
I have not installed python before and what about the newer version that I installed?

OS --> macOS Big Sur

IDE--> PyCharm

Comment: have you tried to launch the console with `python3`?

Comment: sounds like version 2.7.16 was preinstalled. make sure you installed it in the right way (usually with updating python path)

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: @diggusbickus I did type [ python3 --version] and it showed the the newer version but im using Pycharm as the IDE .. so which version im using?

Answer (score 0):

macOS Big Sur comes pre-installed with Python 2.7. That is why you have version 2.7.16 installed on your PC. Uninstalling Python on a Mac is rather complicated, you can keep both Python 2 and Python 3. Just make sure to refer to Python 3.1 as `python3` in the console.

To check what version PyCharm is using, go to Settings > Project Interpreter. If it's using Python 2.7, you can change it to Python 3.1.

Comment: you don't have any idea why python 2 is on op's computer, it looks like a terrible advice

Comment: @diggusbickus No matter why Python 2.7.16 is on the OP's computer, the answer stays the same.

Comment: my operating system is MAcOs

Comment: yes it matters, you don't which programs installed need python2 and uninstalling might break something

Comment: @diggusbickus I have updated the answer based on the OP's OS.